# WebGL transparent gradient mask at edge

Tags: glsl, webgl, mask, fragment-shader

I need to make a feature in WebGL, where I have horizontal list of meshes (example 20) and I want to show only 3 and 2 at edge are fade in/fade out. And it slowly animates from one side no another (sliding to left or right).

[image]

**Here is a sample code, how it is done using CSS.** (https://jsfiddle.net/jqsLh4vg/91/)

What would be possible options to have this kind of effect?

---

My current approach, what I am trying (could be not the most performant solution):

1. Calculate visible area
2. Calculate how much visible area (in percentage) each mesh is visible in visible area on **each render**

[image]

3. Draw gradient using frag shader at the edges (here it is were I stucked and can't figure out the solution)

But maybe there is easier approach for this kind of effect? (Imagine if I have 100 elements and I need to manually calculate their visible area on each render time).

Comment: Just an idea, rather than calculating the visible area, you could instead do a simple algorithm that checks the point's distance to the edge and set a color/alpha based on that.